# Using f2py with windows x64 and Intel Fortran

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, intel-fortran, f2py

I'm trying to achieve in using f2py on windows 8, x64, with Intel Fortran Compiler.

I've tried two things :

1) install via windows 64x installer. http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
NumPy is correctly installed, but no compiler found when executing f2py -c --help-fcompiler
I got :

```
Fortran compilers found:
Compilers available for this platform, but not found:
  --fcompiler=absoft    Absoft Corp Fortran Compiler
  --fcompiler=compaqv   DIGITAL or Compaq Visual Fortran Compil
  --fcompiler=g95       G95 Fortran Compiler
  --fcompiler=gnu       GNU Fortran 77 compiler
  --fcompiler=gnu95     GNU Fortran 95 compiler
  --fcompiler=intelem   Intel Fortran Compiler for 64-bit apps
  --fcompiler=intelev   Intel Visual Fortran Compiler for Itani
  --fcompiler=intelv    Intel Visual Fortran Compiler for 32-bi
  --fcompiler=intelvem  Intel Visual Fortran Compiler for 64-bi
Compilers not available on this platform:
  --fcompiler=compaq   Compaq Fortran Compiler
  --fcompiler=hpux     HP Fortran 90 Compiler
  --fcompiler=ibm      IBM XL Fortran Compiler
  --fcompiler=intel    Intel Fortran Compiler for 32-bit apps
  --fcompiler=intele   Intel Fortran Compiler for Itanium apps
  --fcompiler=lahey    Lahey/Fujitsu Fortran 95 Compiler
  --fcompiler=mips     MIPSpro Fortran Compiler
  --fcompiler=nag      NAGWare Fortran 95 Compiler
  --fcompiler=none     Fake Fortran compiler
  --fcompiler=pathf95  PathScale Fortran Compiler
  --fcompiler=pg       Portland Group Fortran Compiler
  --fcompiler=sun      Sun or Forte Fortran 95 Compiler
  --fcompiler=vast     Pacific-Sierra Research Fortran 90 Compi
```

2) trying to achieve a manual build with : http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/windows.html 
At setup.py config, I got that all the libraries can be found. 
After achieving setup.py install, and achieved numpy.test(), I had the same problem than above.

Any idea?

Comment: Try initialize your ifortran compiler environment, e.g. `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE\bin\ifortvars.bat" intel64 vs2008`, before running `f2py`.

Comment: Ok, great, that worked. But I have to run ifortvars.bat at each time I open a new dos shell. Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to build Scipy yourself?

Comment: The specific reasaon was that fortran compiler was not found with installer, and I thought that manual build could fix that. But cgohlke solution is the right one.

Comment: No wonder the question didn't get too much attention. It was poorly tagged.

Comment: @cgohlke This doesn't work. When I build the example from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/getting-started.html I keep having `error: extension xxxx has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found`

Comment: @cgohlke almost two years after my last comment, I still have the same issue, found again the same SO question without remembering having already came across it, and here I am ...